# Migrating Images from URL in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Reference to this discussion about migrating images from URL in excel [How can I display a URL as an image in an excel cell?](https://superuser.com/questions/940861/how-can-i-display-a-url-as-an-image-in-an-excel-cell)

The VBA code looks perfect and working, my question here is that how can i place each migrated image in the adjacent cell with specified size.
for example if i have a URL in cell A1, then the image should be placed in cell B1 with size 100X100.

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```
Sub InstallPictures_2()
    Dim i As Long, v As String, shp As Shape
    For i = 1 To 1000
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If v = "" Then Exit For
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures
            .Insert (v)
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
            shp.Top = Cells(i, "B").Top
            shp.Left = Cells(i, "B").Left
            shp.Height = 100
            shp.Width = 100
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The code is working just as needed, thanks a lot. However, i have one concern, it is very slow, one hour to migrate 60 items, how can speed up the process or what is the part that causing this time of execution, is it the migration or resizing or what. Thanks a lot , appreciated.

Comment: @Christine  The code is slow on my system as well.  I get a modest improvement in speed by opening my browser **before** running the code.

Comment: @Christine  You are quite welcome!