# Displaying country flags (from alphanumeric codes) in spreadsheet cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Can I somehow trick Excel's auto-formatting capabilities into displaying ISO 639 country codes (alpha-2 as in [ccTLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) and [emojis](https://emojipedia.org/flags/)) as flags?

I don't care much whether the code is still shown or becomes hidden then.

Unlike all other vendors, Microsoft does not render emoji [regional indicator symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol) sequences (RIS, U+1F1E6–FF) as national flag symbols, otherwise I would try to bump the charcode accordingly (depending on lowercase/uppercase). (Although I'm not sure whether or how that could work at all.)

Example: `UN` or `un` becomes  (or some kind of graphic)

Comment: An idea to try: Create a file:// hyperlink to an image on disk with a formula based on the country code -  NOTE: I'm not sure it is possible as I have NOT tried ti.

Comment: Windows does not display emoji flags. You might be able to download a file of `.png` images and display those.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume Column A has the country names and Column B the country codes. Let use Column C for the flags' hyperlinks. The flags will be downloaded from [Flagpedia](https://superuser.com/a/1331028/855367). In `C1`, enter the following formula:

```
="https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/w702/" & LOWER(B1) & ".webp"
```

Drag to fill the other cells. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA Editor, on the left insert a module, then enter the code below. I modified the code from this [answer](https://flagpedia.net/index) to get column A''s last row and to use webp file (this can be changed/removed

```
Option Explicit
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Filename As String

Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol, lRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row of column A
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C" & lRow)   'Set the range of the URLs
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    
    For Each cell In rng
    
        Filename = cell
        If InStr(LCase(Filename), "webp") > 0 Then   '<--- ONLY USES webp
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename).Select
            Set theShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
            If theShape Is Nothing Then GoTo isnill
            xCol = cell.Column + 1
            Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
           ' xRg.Clear
            With theShape
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Width = 60
                .Height = 32
                If i = 0 Then
                    .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) 'Adjust the top location of the first row's image --Should be re-adjust
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    .Top = xRg.Top + 10 + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2 'Adjust the top location of subsequent rows' images --Should be re-adjust
                End If
                .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
            End With
            
            xRg.RowHeight = theShape.Height  'Adjust row height to fit the image
            xRg.ColumnWidth = 10             'Adjust the column height to fit the image
            
isnill:
            Set theShape = Nothing
            Range("A2").Select
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now

End Sub
```

When the code finishes to run, the flags are displayed next to the URLs in Column D. You might have to re-write the part of the code where the image is inserted on the worksheet. I re-adjusted to fit the height and width of my worksheet.

[image]